# Возврат массива из метода, что в коде не так?

Tags: c#

Прошу мне объяснить, что в этом коде не так ?

```
public void someMethod(string[] cats)
{
   cats = { "tiger", "lion", "leopard" };

}
```

Визуал студио ругается.

Comment: Нужно учить теорию. Void вообще ничего не возвращает.

Comment: В крайнем случае public void someMethod( out string[] cats)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Массивы в C# создаются с помощью ключевого слова new, объявления типа элементов массива, скобок [] и количества элементов в массиве (опционально):

```
int[] a = new int[2];
int[] b = new int[];
```

В случае, если массив инициализируется сразу, тип можно опустить (он будет выведен из типов элементов):

```
int[] b = new [] { 1, 2 };
```

А вообще, что вы хотите сделать?

Если установить в переданный массив новые значения *в рамках метода*, то:

```
public void someMethod(string[] cats)
{
   cats = new string[] { "tiger", "lion", "leopard" };
}
```

Если новые значения нужны и *после* выполнения метода, тогда надо пользоваться ключевым словом [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14akc2c7.aspx):

```
public void someMethod(ref string[] cats)
{
   cats = new string[] { "tiger", "lion", "leopard" };
}
```

Если вам нужно просто вернуть новые значения, то так:

```
public string[] someMethod(string[] cats)
{
    return new string [] { "tiger", "lion", "leopard" };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Ваш код не заполняет существующий массив, он создает новый.
2. Ваш код не возвращает массив. Он просто создает его (и тут же выбрасывает вникуда).

Должно быть что-то вроде:

```
public string[] someMethod()
{
    return new string [] { "tiger", "lion", "leopard" };
}
```

Comment: 0. Ваш код не компилируется :).

Comment: ну это же не "напишите за меня". у меня тоже код регулярно не компилируется, бывает :)

Answer (score 2):

Надо писать так

```
 public void someMethod(string[] cats)
 {
     cats =  new string[] { "tiger", "lion", "leopard" };
 }
```